# Converting a string that's concatenate with variable to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't think it thinks this is a variable. 
I have a global variable `dummy1, dummy2, dummy3,` etc. I keep getting undefined when I do `console.log(dummy1)`. 
I want to append the 1,2,3 to the word dummy and save whatever I have into my global. This isn't working and I don't even think it is efficient but not sure what to do?

```
for(var i = 1; i<3; i++){
    if(numberSelect == i){
        window["dummy"[i]]=numberSelect;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is window? Can you include more code because we cannot see the definitions of the dummy variables or what numberSelect is.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy window is javascript global where all base variables are :)

Comment: @hardy, sure it is, but its being treated like an array here ?!

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
window["dummy" + i] = numberSelect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this approach.

```
   window.CustomStorage = {};
   window.CustomStorage["dummy"+[i]]=numberSelect;
```

And you can retrieve it like

```
   window.CustomStorage.dummy1 or simply CustomStorage.dummy1
```

So basic idea is you save all your dynamic stuff into a object called `CustomStorage` and retrieve it by using the property name. ie  dummy1, dummy2 etc